# Notation - meaning of mod(x,y)

Tags: notation

Reading about AKS primality test I've encountered the expression $(x+1)^n \equiv x^n+1 \mod{(n, x^r-1)}$. What does the notation $x\equiv y\mod{(r,s)}$ mean in general?
Is it simply $x \equiv y \pmod r\pmod s$?

Comment: What is $r$ in this context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example is means modulo the ideal of the
polynomial ring $\Bbb Z[x]$ generated by $n$ and $x^r-1$.
This ideal can be denoted as $(n,x^r-1)$ which equals $n\Bbb Z[x]+(x^r-1)\Bbb Z[x]$. Your congruence means that $(x+1)^n-(x^n+1)$ is an element of this ideal.

Comment: I messed up the notation I copied from wikipedia. See Matthew Daly's copy. Does this answer hold also for the notation $\pmod{x^r-1,n}$?

Comment: @GottlobtFrege That's the same ideal.